# Toggele dropdown menu with icons in bootstrap

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to toggle Pause and Enable dropdown options, when clicked it would change the icon and rename Pause to Enable and enable to pause when again clicked.

[image]

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Bootstrap demo</title>
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-rbsA2VBKQhggwzxH7pPCaAqO46MgnOM80zW1RWuH61DGLwZJEdK2Kadq2F9CUG65" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Material+Symbols+Outlined:opsz,wght,FILL,GRAD@20..48,100..700,0..1,-50..200" />   
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Click more options icon</h1>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-kenU1KFdBIe4zVF0s0G1M5b4hcpxyD9F7jL+jjXkk+Q2h455rYXK/7HAuoJl+0I4" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    
<div class="wactions-l9zgqjql">
        <div class="btn-group">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm border-0 text-primary material-symbols-outlined" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">more_horiz</button>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-lg-end" style="">
                <li><a class="dropdown-item menu-switch pause" href="#"><span class="material-symbols-outlined align-middle fs-6">pause</span> Pause</a></li>
                <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#"><span class="material-symbols-outlined align-middle fs-6">share</span> Share</a></li>
                <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#"><span class="material-symbols-outlined align-middle fs-6">content_copy</span> Copy</a></li>
                <li><a class="dropdown-item tdelete" href="#"><span class="material-symbols-outlined align-middle fs-6">delete</span> Delete</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
</div>
<script>

$(".menu-switch").on("click",function(event){

if($(this).hasClass("pause"))
{
alert(true)
    $(this).parent().html(`<a class="dropdown-item menu-switch" href="#"><span class="material-symbols-outlined align-middle fs-6">play_arrow</span> Enable</a>`)
}
else
{
alert(false)
    $(this).parent().html(`<a class="dropdown-item menu-switch pause" href="#"><span class="material-symbols-outlined align-middle fs-6">pause</span> Pause</a>`)
}
    
})
</script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could include both variants and show them alternately.
This collapses/hide one inner div and shows the other.
Ok, it's a bit of a hack but it works without js.

```html
     <li>
        <a class="dropdown-item text-toggle" data-bs-toggle="collapse" href="#idPause" aria-expanded="true">
            <div class="menu-switch pause text-expanded collapse show" id="idPause">
                <span class="material-symbols-outlined align-middle fs-6">pause</span> Pause
            </div>
            <div class="menu-switch text-collapsed">
                <span class="material-symbols-outlined align-middle fs-6">play_arrow</span> Enabled
            </div>
        </a>
    </li>
```

The necessary css

```css
    .text-toggle[aria-expanded=false] .text-expanded {
        display: none;
    }

    .text-toggle[aria-expanded=true] .text-collapsed {
        display: none;
    }
```

The CSS just toggles the paused/enabled visibility.
The JS still works the same way.

```js
    $(".menu-switch").on("click",function(event){
        if($(this).hasClass("pause"))
        {
            alert(true);
        }
        else
        {
            alert(false);
        }
    })
```

Comment: I need this using jquery and not the css.

Comment: To me, that's not clear from the question. Anyway, I've updated my answer.

Comment: Apologies, my mistake, I presumed this is a jq or js solution. didnt even think of css solution. Thanks for your answer.